# Getting error MavenResolutionException

Tags: java, maven-3

Can anybody elaborate https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException 
this Exception in Maven? and its Solution.

I have clean the .m2 file also. Still I am getting this exception.

Comment: The link clearly states: 

> This error generally occurs when Maven could not download
> dependencies.

You have a dependency what couldn't be downloaded. Post the exception text so we can help.

Comment: All the Dependency are downloaded. No Error on pom.xml also. All are good. While starting the jetty, I am getting this kind of error.

Comment: Have you checked if the generated package contains the referred dependency? Have you tried to deploy the application in a way that not depends of the IDE (if it's your actual scenario)?

Comment: Sorry JoaoPiccinini , I didn't get what you wanna to suggest.

Comment: Could you add (to the question) a more detailed information about the error?
Example:
"Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project acme:child-alpha:jar:1.0: [...]"